# Apply procedure on previous result

Tags: scheme

Given a list of lists as an input, I want to execute a procedure such that the final result would be:

```
(define (thing . lists) ; list of lists (l1 l2 ... lN)
  ;returns ...f(f(f(l1 l2) l3) lN)...
)
```

So for example:

```
(thing '(a b) '(c d) '(e f))
```

...would result in `f(f((a b) (c d)) (e f))`

I am fighting with folding, lambda, apply and map, but I can't figure out right way.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `f()` you want to apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input has *at least* two lists and that `f` was previously defined:

```
(define (thing . lists)
  (foldr (lambda (lst acc)
           (f acc lst))
         (f (car lists) (cadr lists))
         (cddr lists)))
```

For example:

```
(define f append)
(thing '(a b) '(c d) '(e f))
=> '(a b c d e f)
```